# How to write a perfect Abbreviated Function Template?

Tags: c++, templates, auto, c++20

What are the best practices to write abbreviated function templates?

I understand, that since C++20, the following is valid code:

```
void f(auto&& val) {...}
```

Is it essential to use decltype(auto) as the return type of such functions?
In particular, is the following code the right way to write abbreviated function templates?

```
decltype(auto) f(auto&& val) {return std::forward<decltype(val)>(val+=2);}
```

- How should I specialize the above function?

```
//something like this?: 
template<> decltype(auto) f<MyClass>(MyClass& val) {...}
```

Comment: `void f(auto&& val) {...}` is not valid code.

Comment: @Axalo - It is due to the C++20 tag

Comment: @Axalo It is, since C++20. Ignoring `...`, that is.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I believe that the first two questions are the same (basially I just gave a "default" example in the second question to the first). I will remove the third question and ask it seperately.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I've already got several answers so I will leave the question as it is. I will try to ask a more on-point question next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it essential to use `decltype(auto)` as the return type of such functions?

Depends on what you're returning. Using an abbreviated template doesn't change anything in this regard.

> In particular, is the following code the right way to write abbreviated function templates?
>
> ```
> decltype(auto) f(auto&& val) {return std::forward<decltype(val)>(val+=2);}
> ```

`decltype(auto)` is used correctly. But `val` should be forwarded before doing anything with it:

```
std::forward<decltype(val)>(val) += 2;
```

Alternatively, you could write:

```
decltype(val)(val) += 2;
```

> How should I specialize the above function?
>
> ```
> //something like this?: 
> template<> decltype(auto) f<MyClass>(MyClass& val) {...}
> ```

The parameter has type `T &&`, where `T` is the implicit template parameter. So it must be either `f<MyClass>(MyClass&& val)` or `f<MyClass &>(MyClass& val)`. You could also omit the template parameter, and let the compiler infer it.

But note that this specialization applies only to a non-const, rvalue (or lvalue) `MyClass` argument. If you want to specialize for all value categories and combinations of cv-qualifers of the argument, you'll need to overload it instead (because you can't partially specialize functions):

```
template <typename T>
requires std::same_as<int, std::remove_cvref_t<T>>
decltype(auto) f(T&& val) {return 42;}
```

Or:

```
decltype(auto) f(auto&& val)
requires std::same_as<int, std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(val)>>
{return 42;}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I undid the deletion of the second part of the question, to make your answer easier to follow for somebody reading this.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it essential to use `decltype(auto)` as the return type of such functions?

No.

From [[dcl.fct]/18/sentence-2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct#18.sentence-2) [extract, **emphasis** mine]:

> An abbreviated function template **is equivalent** to a function template ([temp.fct]) whose *template-parameter-list* **includes one invented type *template-parameter* for each generic parameter type placeholder** of the function declaration, in order of appearance. For a *placeholder-type-specifier* **of the form `auto`**, the invented parameter is an **unconstrained *type-parameter***.

Thus, there is no essential difference between regular function templates and abbreviated function templates w.r.t. the usage of `decltype(auto)` as return type; it simply gives you the ability to perfectly forward a return type (as with a regular function template).

---

> How should I specialize the above function?

As per [[dcl.fct]/18](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct#18) [extract, **emphasis** mine]:

> [...] [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<typename T>     concept C1 = /* ... */;
> template<typename T>     concept C2 = /* ... */;
> template<typename... Ts> concept C3 = /* ... */;
>
> void g1(const C1 auto*, C2 auto&);
> void g2(C1 auto&...);
> void g3(C3 auto...);
> void g4(C3 auto);
> ```
>
> These declarations are functionally equivalent (but not equivalent) to
> the following declarations.
>
> ```
> template<C1 T, C2 U> void g1(const T*, U&);
> template<C1... Ts>   void g2(Ts&...);
> template<C3... Ts>   void g3(Ts...);
> template<C3 T>       void g4(T);
> ```
>
> **Abbreviated function templates can be specialized like all function templates.**
>
> ```
> template<> void g1<int>(const int*, const double&); // OK, specialization of g1<int, const double>
> ```
>
> — end example ]

you can specialize, say

```
void f(auto&& val) { (void)val;}
```

as

```
template<>
void f<int>(int&& val) { (void)val;}
```

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/I34KEKQ6eBwZ5CGc).